# nginx container cannot see the certificate in shared certbot volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, certbot

So i have certbot run as a container and create a normal and wildcard certificate with the following command

```
 sudo docker run -it --rm --name certbot -v certbot_certs:/etc/letsencrypt -v /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot -v ~/.secrets/certbot:/.secrets/certbot certbot/dns-digitalocean certonly --dns-digitalocean --dns-digitalocean-credentials /.secrets/certbot/do.ini --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --email xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d <domain> -d *.<domain>
```

the operation is successful as shown in the terminal result

```
Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2023-10-08.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.
```

my docker-compose.ylm has this declared in the config of the nginx container

```
      volumes:
        - certbot_certs:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
        - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot:ro
```

and the nginx.conf contains

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    
    server_name geokotze.dev www.geokotze.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/<domain>/privkey.pem;
    
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

a check of the certbot_certs volume tree shows the certificates under /live//

so from what i understand this should work.

And yet i get the error

```
[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/etc/nginx/ssl/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)
```

I am too dumb and tired (currently working 10 hour kitchen shifts trying to become a dev) to keep trying to figure this out on my own. Before i tried to run it with compose it worked so i am sure i fucked something in the compose.yml but i cant't figure out what.

Help me fellow nerds. Please.

Also any tips are valued and would not be taken as condescending.

<3

I was expecting it to work and if i spend more time troubleshooting instead of sleeping the chef will add me to the sauce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've worked with `docker-compose`, you are probably familiar with the fact that service names in your `docker-compose.yaml` are modified (by adding a project prefix and an instance number) to form container names.  That is, if I have the following `docker-compose.yaml` in a directory named `example`:

```
services:
    web:
      image: alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

Then I end up with:

```
$ docker ps --format='{{ .Names }}'
example-web-1
```

The same thing happens for volumes. If I have:

```
services:
    web:
      image: alpinelinux/darkhttpd
      volumes:
        - certbot_certs:/etc/nginx/ssl

volumes:
  certbot_certs:
```

Then I end up with:

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     example_certbot_certs
```

In other words, the `certbot_certs` volume in your `docker-compose.yaml` file is **not** the same as the volume you created with your `docker run` command line.

If you want your compose stack to refer to an **existing** volume, you need to mark the volume as `external`, like this:

```
services:
    web:
      image: alpinelinux/darkhttpd
      volumes:
        - certbot_certs:/etc/nginx/ssl

volumes:
  certbot_certs:
    external: true
```

Comment: I love you kind stranger. Thank you for providing an explanation that taught me a few things too. Have a lovely day